# Where do prints go when running Flask with Apache?

Tags: python, apache, logging, flask

I just deployed the first website I built with Flask to a production server. I enabled logging using the `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` to `/log/myapp.log`, with which I can log messages using for example:

```
current_app.logger.error('this is a massive error')
```

This works fine. It makes me wonder about some pieces of code though, which contain for example `print 'some info here'` which I used while debugging. Where do these printouts go? Into the void `/dev/null` or somewhere else? Is there a possibility to catch them somehow?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: the server terminal....did u check there?

Comment: @Ja8zyjits - But I start apache using `sudo service apache2 start`, so where should I find the server terminal?

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi? Or uwsgi? Apache alone doesn't do wsgi, which is needed for python Web apps like flask.

Comment: I use `mod_wsgi`, can I catch that output if I use `uwsgi`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything you output using `print` goes to the standard output, i.e. `/dev/stdout` on a Unix server (by default). Since apache is running as a service, you will probably never see these output.

One way to deal with this is to redirect the standard output of your scripts to some files:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = open('output.logs', 'w')
>>> print('Hello World!') # Nothing appears bellow
>>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # Reset to the standard output
>>> open('output.logs', 'r').read()
'Hello World!\n'
```

Comment: But the output only visible when app ends an/or you reset the output stream

Answer (score 2):

Print statements in app running on apache can be usually seen in the Apache logs. You can check this file: `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`

Comment: That file is empty.. :(

Comment: what about `/var/log/apache2/access.log?`

Comment: My print statements are going to apache `error_log` whether I print to stdout or stderr.